# How to insert a new record or save changes to an existing record

Tags: c#, sql, datacontext

So up until now I have been able to write a query function for my database, but I am stumped when it comes to writing an update function. My query function works just fine.

```
public PATIENT_IDS GetPatientIDS(string patientID)
{
    string ID = patientID;

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "\\SQLExpress";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "pchr42563";
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    DataContext patientContext = new DataContext(builder.ConnectionString);

    PATIENT_IDS patient = (from p in patientContext.GetTable<PATIENT_IDS>() 
                           where p.PATIENT_ID == ID 
                           select p).First();
    return patient;

}
```

But I cannot wrap my head about how to attach to it correctly to change the record. I imagine it should be

```
public void UpdatePatientIDS(PATIENT_ID patient)
{
    PATIENT_ID newPatient = patient;

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "\\SQLExpress";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "pchr42563";
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    DataContext patientContext = new DataContext(builder.ConnectionString);

    //this is the part that does not exist but I feel it should
    patientContext.PATIENT_ID.add(newPatient);
    patientContext.SubmitChanges();

}
```

I do not know if this matters, but it is part of the web service code and the client application is passing the PATIENT_ID over a proxy.

Here is my definition of the PATIENT_IDS class found in my conract

```
namespace PCHRContracts
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Table(Name = "PATIENT_IDS")]
[DataContract]
public partial class PATIENT_IDS
{
    public PATIENT_IDS()
    {
        this.ALLERGIES = new HashSet<ALLERGy>();
        this.CONDITIONs = new HashSet<CONDITION>();
        this.IMMUNIZATIONS = new HashSet<IMMUNIZATION>();
        this.MED_PROCEDURE = new HashSet<MED_PROCEDURE>();
        this.MEDICATIONS = new HashSet<MEDICATION>();
        this.TEST_RESULTS = new HashSet<TEST_RESULTS>();
    }

    [Column]
    [DataMember]
    public string PATIENT_ID { get; set; }

   //other code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use InsertOnSubmit() :

```
DataContext patientContext = new DataContext(builder.ConnectionString);

//this is the part that does not exist but I feel it should
patientContext.PATIENT_IDS.InsertOnSubmit(newPatient);
patientContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I had read that somewhere but but for some reason it does not recognize patientContext.PATIENT_IDS. I had mistakenly assumed it was obsolete code. Is there a particular library I am missing? I have using System.Data.Linq;

Comment: To be clear it recognizes patientContext but does not recognize the PATIENT_IDS class in that call. It does accept that as a proper class when I pass the variable, however. The error I get is    Error 1 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' does not contain a definition for 'PATIENT_IDS' and no extension method 'PATIENT_IDS' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\PCHR Webservice\App_Code\PCHRService.cs 104 24 PCHR Webservice

Comment: Try PATIENT_IDs with a small s.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after fretting for hours over what I thought should be so simple I figured it out, although I do not know why it has to be like this so no other examples on the web had it like this.

```
patientContext.GetTable<PATIENT_IDS>().InsertOnSubmit(newPatient);
```

My clue should have been my own previous code in my GetPatient() function

```
PATIENT_IDS patient = (from p in patientContext.GetTable<PATIENT_IDS>() 
                       where p.PATIENT_ID == ID 
                       select p).First();
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Seems very strange that you would need to do it this way.  Your .dbml file should contain a definition for the PATIENT_IDS table.  Did you use SQLMetal or the Designer to create your DataContext ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384396.aspx

Comment: The book we use "Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Step by Step" had us use the Entity Data Model Wizard which generated the entity. It might be my amateur knowledge but otherwise the code I had above was how I connected with it. Otherwise, it was an .mdf file our professor created ran some scripts. Are any of those things what you are looking for?